# '429 Too many requests' using guzzle with laravel

Tags: laravel, request, guzzle

*What I'm trying to do*:

Send a post request using postman to a laravel API which in-turn sends 2 post requests using guzzle, one request to the same laravel application api and other to 3rd party api like:

```
$responses = all([
    $client->postAsync('www.someurl.com/here', ['form_params' => $postData]),
    $client->postAsync($hook, ['form_params' => $sendData])
])->wait();
```

Here, the 1st request is to the same application and the second request to the 3rd party API.

*What I did*:

When I did this same thing locally, I had to open 2 local servers in ports 8000 and 8001 since PHP's local server is single-threaded, and it worked perfectly. For only one server, the 2nd request would be blocked indefinitely. But after moving it to production, I faced this `429 too many requests` issue. So, I did some research and there is a thing in Laravel called throttling, which is defined in the kernel. Mine has:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

*What I don't understand*:

This means that the middleware allows 60 requests per minute right? But here I am only sending 2, maybe in the future, it could go up to 4. Is this the problem that I am facing? Or is it my architecture? I can't comment this out (as per some suggestions) because of obvious security concerns. Is there any other way or workaround to this problem?

Comment: 429 likely means that the 3rd party application is throttling your requests maybe because it's too busy or because you've sent too many requests in a short period of time. Usually they specify what their limits are in their documentation (or should anyway). I don't think there's anything you can do on your end other than wait and try again later

Comment: This 3rd party application works perfectly with the same conditions in local though, would it be any different anywhere else?

Comment: It's possible they are throttling requests coming from your hosting provider because they might get a lot from that origin regardless if they are all coming from you

Comment: I logged everything and its still gives me 'too many requests', but one thing I found out, its originating from the same application, not from the 3rd party application

Comment: For now I'm using Laravels request rather than guzzle to use internal APIs and it seems to work.